# Why run apache superset in production was very very difficult?

Tags: apache-superset

```
Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/xxx/venv/bin/superset_config.py]
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
2019-09-23 21:52:03,168:INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But in my config file /xxx/venv/bin/superset_config.py:

```
SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_ADDRESS = "192.168.xx.cc"
SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_PORT = 8088
```

Why Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/...

Feeling very crushed...

Comment: Please specify the command line used to start superset instance.

Answer (score -1):

If you using pip installation to run Superset, use

superset run --host 192.168.xx.cc --port 8088

But if you are using Docker, I don't know how to do it :/

The SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_ADDRESS and SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_PORT is not the correct setting, they exist for different purpose.